# Terms & Condition in AWS cognito

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Can we add **terms and conditions** link with checkbox in the Aws Cognito's hosted UI?

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance...